# Canceling dynamic script by removing script tag doesn't work in FF

Tags: javascript, firefox, dynamic

I'm adding dynamic script by creating a script tag, setting its source and then adding the tag to the DOM. It works as expected, the script is getting downloaded and executes. However sometimes I would like to cancel script execution *before* it was downloaded. So I do it by removing the script tag from the DOM.

In IE9, Chrome and Safari it works as expected - after the script tag is removed from the DOM it doesn't execute.

However it doesn't work in Firefox - script executes even if I remove it from the DOM or change it its src to "" or anything else I tried, I cannot stop the execution of a script after it was added to the DOM. Any suggestions?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

How about some sort of callback arrangement? Rather than have the dynamically added script simply execute itself when it loads, have it call a function within your main script which will decide whether to go ahead. You could have the main script's function simply return true or false (execute / don't execute), or it could accept a callback function as a parameter so that it can decide exactly when to start the dynamic script - that way if you had several dynamic scripts the main script could wait until they're all loaded and then execute them in a specific order.

In your main script JS:

```
function dynamicScriptLoaded(scriptId,callback) {
   if (scriptId === something && someOtherCondition())
      callback();
   // or store the callback for later, put it on a timeout, do something
   // to sequence it with other callbacks from other dynamic scripts,
   // whatever...
}
```

In your dynamically added script:

```
function start() {
   doMyThing();
   doMyOtherThing();
}

if (window.dynamicScriptLoaded)
   dynamicScriptLoaded("myIdOrName",start);
else
   start();
```

The dynamic script checks to see if there is a dynamicScriptLoaded() function defined, expecting it to be in the main script (feel free to upgrade this to a more robust test, i.e., checking that dynamicScriptLoaded actually is a function). If it is defined it calls it, passing a callback function. If it isn't defined it assumes it is OK to go ahead and execute itself - or you can put whatever fallback functionality there that you like.

UPDATE: I changed the `if` test above since `if(dynamicScriptLoaded)` would give an error if the function didn't exist, whereas `if(window.dynamicScriptLoaded)` will work. Assuming the function is global - obviously this could be changed if using a namespacing scheme.

In the year since I originally posted this answer I've become aware that the [yepnope.js loader](http://yepnopejs.com/) allows you to load a script without executing it, so it should be able to handle the situation blankSlate mentioned in the comment below. yepnope.js is only 1.7kb.

Comment: Thanks! Yes if I could change the scripts that I'm loading dynamically I would definitely go with this approach to have more control over whether and how the scripts execute. However the constraint I have in this scenario is that I cannot change dynamic scripts or add any checks to them.

Comment: @blankSlate - I don't really have any further suggestions beyond not referencing the dynamic script until you are 100% sure you want it executed and won't need to cancel. Though I'm wondering why you'd need to cancel the script after it has already started downloading. I mean, is the script so big that the user has time to take some action while it is still downloading and you want to cancel it then?